# Get variables from a Regex Expression

Tags: java

I'm trying to validate the following:

```
/w username message
```

Here is my regex expression:

```
if (input.toLowerCase().matches("^/w(\\s+)([0-9a-zA-Z].*)(\\s+)([0-9a-zA-Z ].*)$")) {
...
```

How do I get the username and the message as variables?

```
String username = ???
String message = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\/w\\s+(?<username>\\w+)\\s+(?<message>.+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/w username message");

if(matcher.matches()) {
    String username = matcher.group("username");
    String message = matcher.group("message");
}
```

[www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/D0E55Q/1)